# Read page XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest, domparser

Hey guys, this is driving me absolutely insane so I wanted to ask the experts on this site to see if you know how to do it =)

I'm trying to create some javascript code that can read out elements of a web page (eg. what does the first paragraph say?). Here's what I have so far, but it doesnt work and I cant figure out why:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var req;
// handle onreadystatechange event of req object
function processReqChange() {
    // only if req shows "loaded"
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // only if "OK"
        if (req.status == 200) {
            //document.write(req.responseText);
            alert("done loading");

            var responseDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(req.responseText, "text/xml");
            alert(responseDoc.evaluate("//title",responseDoc,null,
                        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue);
         } 
         else {
            document.write("<error>could not load page</error>");
         }
    }
}

req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
req.open("GET", "http://www.apple.com", true);
req.send(null);
// -->
```

The alert that keeps appearing is "null" and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: simple question...have you tried console.log'ing the responseText to ensure it is valid XML? Could you submit the XML for use to see? From what I can see, your xPath string is good, as is your use of evaluate...

Comment: the way ill be using it the response wont always be valid xml. not sure if this is the problem, but how could i make it read dirty xml as well? (or just use the dom structure)

Comment: The DomParser is very picky about properly formatted XML. I have had problems with it myself. It is not very forgiving about a missed '>' and such.

Comment: Oh, you could try prepending `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` to the start of the XML, to ensure the parser treats it as XML

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to cross domain restriction... unless you're hosting your web page on apple.com. :) You could also use jQuery and avoid writing all that out and/or dealing with any common possible cross-browser XML loading/parsing issues. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

**Update:**
Looks like it may have something to do with the source web site's Content-Type or something similar... For example, this code seems to work... (Notice the domain loaded...)

```
var req;
// handle onreadystatechange event of req object
function processReqChange() {
    // only if req shows "loaded"
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // only if "OK"

        if (req.status == 200) {
            //document.write(req.responseText);
            //alert("done loading");
            //alert(req.responseText);

            var responseDoc = new DOMParser();
            var xmlText = responseDoc.parseFromString(req.responseText, "text/xml");
            try{
              alert(xmlText.evaluate("//title",xmlText,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue);
            }catch(e){
              alert("error");
            }
         } 
         else {
            document.write("could not load page");
         }
    }
}

req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
req.open("GET", "http://www.jquery.com", true);
req.send(null);
```

I also tried loading espn.com and google.com, and noticed they both have "Content-Encoding:gzip" so maybe that's the issue, just guessing though.

Comment: Nah, it loads the text. You can check this by doing alert(req.responseText); it will display all the html code from the apple website.

Comment: In what browser? I'm seeing "could not load page" in Chrome on Mac OS, after uploading it to my server. And when I alert req.responseText it's an empty alert. Are you using a valid DOCTYPE?

Comment: did you include the closing </script>? for soem reason stackoverflow cut it off

Comment: yep! are you testing on a web server, or loading up the file locally?

Comment: loading it locally. and its on safari as well (just realized i didnt answer that before)

Comment: anyway, regardless, you won't be able to load data across domains. to do that using javascript, you'll need to use something like YQL and jQuery. like so: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: well its only going to be used on the iphone safari browser (as part of an iphone app). would those technologies work that way?

Comment: they should. also, btw i'm seeing your code work with some web sites, and some not... thinking it may have something to do with the doctype or content-type of the site... just updated my answer w/ a site tht seems to work. (jquery.com)